# Unit Test MVC with ASP.NET Dev Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to confirm that my "HomeController" class is being selected by the route I've created.  So I have a test like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost:14478/home")]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("$(SolutionDir)\\MvcBuildApp")]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
        MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);
        MvcApplication.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        //This fetches DefaultControllerFactory (for now, anyway...)
        var factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
        //mock a context...
        var httpContext = CreateHttpContext("http://localhost:14478/home", "GET");
        RouteData route = routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        var ctrlInstance = factory.CreateController(new RequestContext(httpContext, route), (string)route.Values["controller"]);

        //ASSERT the instance is of type "HomeController"
        //...
     }
```

It fails, saying that `'http://localhost:14478/home' completed successfully without running the test.`

I noticed that in the VS output window, there is also this message `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:14478`.  I figured Cassini must not be active.  So I chose to launch the site being tested (ctrl+F5) before launching the unit test.  It then changed the VS output to this:

> WebTestAdapter.ConnectToHostAdapter: unexpected exception occured.
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.HostAdapters.AbortTestExecutionException:
>   Error in the application.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.HostAdapters.WebTestAdapter.ConnectToHostAdapter()

To try to resolve this, I've followed the advice of these articles:

- [Debug while running a test in ASP.NET solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243172.aspx)
- [Unit Tests for ASP.NET web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243172.aspx): this discusses the "completed successfully without running a test" error.
- [Configuring ASP.NET Unit Tests](http://www.skonet.com/Articles_Archive/How_To_Configure_ASP_NET_Unit_Tests_in_Visual_Studio_2010.aspx): I got the $(SolutionDir) idea from this article.

...but I still get the error no matter what I do.  Suggestions?

**UPDATE/CLARIFICATION**
This question is **not** about testing MVC routes.  The purpose of this question is to discover how to make ASP.NET MVC properly initialized to allow more "in depth" automated testing.  I have chosen a "route testing" scenario, against the DefaultControllerFactory, merely as an example.  In this example, the DefaultControllerFactory does not behave properly unless ASP.NET MVC is properly initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in reviewing Steve Sandersons MVC testing framework. If you download the source you will have a great example on how to initialize the MVC framwork:

http://blog.codeville.net/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/

Comment: Steven's approach, expressed in the link you provided, is absolutely brilliant.  I could not hardly hope for anything better.  It doesn't answer my question of how I can use the AspNetDevelopmentServerHost and HostType annotations, but it does something equivalent or better - as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common requirement when testing MVC applications, and lucky you, there is a framework that will simplify your life when testing MVC controllers:

The tools is:

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/

And as an example you can create tests with just one line:

```
"~/".ShouldMapTo<HomeController>(controller => controller.Index());
```

As a reference:

http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2009/11/02/unit-testing-asp.net-mvc-routes.aspx

http://www.arrangeactassert.com/how-to-unit-test-asp-net-mvc-controllers/

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify that I'm not actually asking about route testing.  You'll notice that my example test uses the DefaultControllerFactory and has a comment about replacing that factory.  Once the factory is replaced, the MVCContrib TestHelper which you referenced will no longer benefit me.